# Relational DB - When looking to functional dependencies among non-key values, should I look to multi-dependence causers?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Ex: Imagine I have this database

```
A      //primary key
B
C
D
```

All fields depends functionally of the key.

No non-key field depends functionally of another non-key field.

But: `D depends functionally of B and C.`Should I consider this (dependence to multiple fields) when trying to achieve the third normal form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question boils down to this: Are R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> the same?

- R<sub>1</sub>( **A** BCD), A->BCD
- R<sub>2</sub>( **A** BCD), A->BCD, BC->D

Clearly they are different.  R<sub>1</sub> is in at least BCNF as it stands now; R<sub>2</sub> has a transitive dependency, BC->D, so it is no higher than 2NF.

We write attributes using uppercase letters, because uppercase letters represent *sets* in [set theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/basic-set-theory.html). The relational model is based in part on set theory. So, in a real-world modeling job, *A* might represent a set of three columns.

In your example, the fact that the left-and side of one functional dependency is represented by the single letter *A*, and the left-hand side of the other is represented by the two letters *BC* isn't important. Both those left-hand sides might represent two, three, or more columns in a relational table. Normalization through BCNF always takes into account *every* functional dependency you know about, no matter how many letters it takes to express it.

You *could* even rewrite R<sub>2</sub> like this, after doing E = BC. Doesn't change the transitive dependency at all.

- R<sub>2</sub>( **A** ED), A->ED, E->D